# warning: fopen() call

Tags: c, warnings, fopen, std

hi I'm programming with stdlib under linux.

The gcc emits the following warning for the following line of code, any idea why is that?

```
FILE *fd;
if ( fd = fopen( filename, "rw" )== NULL )
{
```

and the warning is:

```
warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast.
```

How this can be happen , according to the stdlib documentation the return type of fopen is FILE*. So why there is a warning still there?Any idea?

--Thanks In Advance--

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
if ((fd = fopen( filename, "rw")) == NULL)
    ^                           ^
```

Otherwise `fd` will take the value 0 or 1 and the `FILE *` itself returned by `fopen` will be lost. So without those parentheses the result of the comparison will be stored in `fd` instead of the `FILE *` itself.

Comment: Worth to note that == has higher precedence than =. That's way that is executed first.

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially assigning `fd` to be `fopen(filename, "rw") == NULL`, as a conditional expression is an integer (0 or 1), you are assigning a pointer from an integer. follow @cnicutar's answer for the fix

Answer (score 0):

```
FILE *fd;
if ( (fd = fopen( filename, "rw" ))== NULL )
{
```

just copy this code it will work....
you just forget to put () arround   "fd = fopen( filename, "rw" )"